# Go - empty slice when return by gin.Context.JSON

Tags: go

if `resp` is struct with slice member like following:

```golang
type MyStruct struct {
    Data  []struct {
        Name        string `json:"name"`
    } `json:"data"`
}
```

```golang
func Something(c *gin.Context) {
    result := make(chan MyStruct, 1)
    go func() {
        resp, _ := Calculate()  // if return empty slice
        fmt.Println(result)     // output: {[]}
        result <- resp
    }()
    
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, <-result) // output: {"data": null}
}
```

Is it possible make the last output `<-result` to `{"data": []}`?

Answer (score 1):

The fmt package prints nil slices the same as empty slices: `[]`.

The json/encoding package makes a distinction between nil slices and empty slices.  A nil slice is encode as `nil` and an empty slice is encoded as `[]`.

To get the expected output, set the Data field to an empty slice:

```
resp.Data = []struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}{}
```

To make this easier, declare a named type for the Data field:

```
type Data struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

type MyStruct struct {
    Data []Data `json:"data"`
}
```

Set the field to the empty slice using:

```
resp.Data = []Data{}
```

Combine this assignment with the variable declaration by using a [short variable declaration](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) and a [composite literal](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals) containing the empty slice:

```
resp := MyStruct{Data: []Data{}}
```

Comment: I declare MyStruct in function Calculate() by `var result MyStruct`. Any easier way to init struct?

Comment: Use a composite literal to initialize the struct.  See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. Looks must declare a named type for the Data field. Cannot declae as  nested struct.

Comment: The named type makes things easier, but is not required.  `result := MyStruct{Data: []struct {Name string \`json:"name"\`}{}}`